# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file - Adobe AIO

Tags: node.js, npm, aio

After running npm install command I am trying to deploy the code using "aio app deploy" but I ended up with below error.

```
"stack": "ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
 ›   https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders\n> <!--\n|   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.\n| \n    at handleParseError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:982:19)\n    at 
 ›   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1101:5\n    at processResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:806:11)\n    at 
 ›   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:866:5\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:407:3\n    at iterateNormalLoaders
 ›    (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:10)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:224:4\n    at 
 ›   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:840:15\n    at Array.eval (eval at create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), 
 ›   <anonymous>:12:1)\n    at runCallbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@adobe/aio-cli/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:15)"
```

[image]

The error occurs on @adobe/aio-cli module and there is no error in custom code. Seems it is expecting some loader to parse. Can anyone tell me how to load a modular in @adobe/aio-cli.